# Cannot find installed certificate in project/ signing  visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I use visual studio 2010 and I am trying to sign my click once application with given certificate. I have done the following:

Downloaded and Installed crt file to CurrentUser/Trusted Root Certification authorities    store.

But when I:

1. open the Signing tab in my project
2. press 'Select from store' button there is no certificate that I installed.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of certificate did you use?

You need to use the Authenticode PKCS 7 standard which uses X.509 v3 certificates to bind an Authenticode-signed files to the identity of a software publisher.

Please review:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487309